# Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 upgrade broke my ZFS

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, zfs

I just upgraded Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 which seems to have broken ZFS. I followed the directions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842316/zfs-install-on-ubuntu-16-04lts/910649#910649) and purged all old ZFS packages.  I then installed zfsutils-linux from the default 16.04 PPAs but whenever I run any ZFS commands I get the following error:

```
:~$ sudo zfs get all
The ZFS modules are not loaded.
Try running '/sbin/modprobe zfs' as root to load them.
```

I've attempted using modprobe as the error messages recommends:

```
:~$ sudo /sbin/modprobe zfs
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'zfs': Invalid argument
```

It seems like ZFS is not installed but apt-get shows that it is:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install zfsutils-linux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
zfsutils-linux is already the newest version (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

I also physically went to my machine rather than using SSH to watch the boot and saw a number of ZFS items FAIL on startup, one of which I believe said something about dependencies, but it went by too fast for me to read all of them.  I attempted to see what they say by looking in boot logs, but I've been unable to find a boot log file that matches the output shown during startup.  Where can I look to see what is actually failing at startup?

Further interesting discovery is that if I use just the zfs command, I get the 'missing command' output, but when adding any command I get the same error message from above.

```
:~$ zfs
missing command
usage: zfs command args ...
where 'command' is one of the following:

        create [-p] [-o property=value] ... <filesystem>
        create [-ps] [-b blocksize] [-o property=value] ... -V <size> <volume>
        destroy [-fnpRrv] <filesystem|volume>
        destroy [-dnpRrv] <filesystem|volume>@<snap>[%<snap>][,...]
        destroy <filesystem|volume>#<bookmark>

        snapshot|snap [-r] [-o property=value] ... <filesystem|volume>@<snap> ..                                                                                                                                                             .
        rollback [-rRf] <snapshot>
        clone [-p] [-o property=value] ... <snapshot> <filesystem|volume>
        promote <clone-filesystem>
        rename [-f] <filesystem|volume|snapshot> <filesystem|volume|snapshot>
        rename [-f] -p <filesystem|volume> <filesystem|volume>
        rename -r <snapshot> <snapshot>
        bookmark <snapshot> <bookmark>

        list [-Hp] [-r|-d max] [-o property[,...]] [-s property]...
            [-S property]... [-t type[,...]] [filesystem|volume|snapshot] ...

        set <property=value> <filesystem|volume|snapshot> ...
        get [-rHp] [-d max] [-o "all" | field[,...]]
            [-t type[,...]] [-s source[,...]]
            <"all" | property[,...]> [filesystem|volume|snapshot] ...
        inherit [-rS] <property> <filesystem|volume|snapshot> ...
        upgrade [-v]
        upgrade [-r] [-V version] <-a | filesystem ...>
        userspace [-Hinp] [-o field[,...]] [-s field] ...
            [-S field] ... [-t type[,...]] <filesystem|snapshot>
        groupspace [-Hinp] [-o field[,...]] [-s field] ...
            [-S field] ... [-t type[,...]] <filesystem|snapshot>

        mount
        mount [-vO] [-o opts] <-a | filesystem>
        unmount [-f] <-a | filesystem|mountpoint>
        share <-a | filesystem>
        unshare <-a | filesystem|mountpoint>

        send [-DnPpRvLe] [-[iI] snapshot] <snapshot>
        send [-Le] [-i snapshot|bookmark] <filesystem|volume|snapshot>
        receive [-vnFu] <filesystem|volume|snapshot>
        receive [-vnFu] [-d | -e] <filesystem>

        allow <filesystem|volume>
        allow [-ldug] <"everyone"|user|group>[,...] <perm|@setname>[,...]
            <filesystem|volume>
        allow [-ld] -e <perm|@setname>[,...] <filesystem|volume>
        allow -c <perm|@setname>[,...] <filesystem|volume>
        allow -s @setname <perm|@setname>[,...] <filesystem|volume>

        unallow [-rldug] <"everyone"|user|group>[,...]
            [<perm|@setname>[,...]] <filesystem|volume>
        unallow [-rld] -e [<perm|@setname>[,...]] <filesystem|volume>
        unallow [-r] -c [<perm|@setname>[,...]] <filesystem|volume>
        unallow [-r] -s @setname [<perm|@setname>[,...]] <filesystem|volume>

        hold [-r] <tag> <snapshot> ...
        holds [-r] <snapshot> ...
        release [-r] <tag> <snapshot> ...
        diff [-FHt] <snapshot> [snapshot|filesystem]

Each dataset is of the form: pool/[dataset/]*dataset[@name]

For the property list, run: zfs set|get

For the delegated permission list, run: zfs allow|unallow
```

What else can I do to troubleshoot this ZFS install?

Comment: Have you tried loading the zfs module?  `sudo modprobe zfs`

Comment: @Charles The result is: 'modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'zfs': Invalid argument'

Comment: @Charles The result is: `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'zfs': Invalid argument`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar problem upgrading from 12.04 to 16.04. Finally got it to work but do not remember exactly what I did (step 2 was not obvious).

1. Remove the old `zfs` packages including the PPA, see [Upgrade to 16.04 LTS from ubuntu server 14.04 LTS with ubuntu-zfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758230/upgrade-to-16-04-lts-from-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts-with-ubuntu-zfs)
2. Remove: `spl-dkms` and (I think) `spl`
3. Reinstall `zfs`

Comment: That did it!  I had looked at that post before so I'm not sure what actually fixed it this time, but here's a list of the things I tried before it started working.  My pool was mounted without even a reboot!


`apt clean

# Remove old ZFS stuff
apt-get remove spl dkms spl-dkms
apt-get autoremove
add-apt-repository --remove ppa:zfs-native/stable`

Comment: That did it!  I had looked at that post before so I'm not sure what actually fixed it this time, but here's a list of the things I tried before it started working.  My pool was mounted without even a reboot!


`apt clean
apt update
apt purge zfs*
apt-get remove spl dkms spl-dkms
apt-get autoremove
add-apt-repository --remove ppa:zfs-native/stable

apt-get install zfsutils-linux
apt-get install spl-dkms`

Comment: Just a note, it's really stupid that you can only edit a comment for 5 minutes before it locks you out on this website!  Hence, why I have 2 almost identical comments above; the 2nd one includes everything I wanted, but since pressing enter accidentally submitted the first one incorrectly and missed the 5 minute timer.

Answer (score 1):

The following series of `root` commands resolved the issue for me.

```
apt clean
apt update
apt purge zfs*
apt remove spl dkms spl-dkms
apt autoremove
add-apt-repository --remove ppa:zfs-native/stable

apt install zfsutils-linux
apt install spl-dkms

reboot -n
```

Comment: I tried this three times and it didn't work until I rebooted after removing everything and before installing zfsutils-linux.